# Azure B2C custom policy external datasource authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to configure Azure B2C in such a way that it prompts the user for a login id and password, these are then authenticated using an external REST call, and it returns an OIDC token containing whatever claims I wish to return in the REST call.

I can make the REST call work and add claims to an existing example policy no problem. The problem is removing the superfluous Azure AD behaviour without breaking the policy.

If the user doesn't exist in the Azure AD Directory, I don't care, I'm not interested in the user having an Azure profile at all, I want all the user data to come from the application's own database, but I haven't found a way to stop Azure from redirecting the user to create a new local AD account if one doesn't already exist.

The documentation is very dense and has a few walk-throughs of how to do a few of the things it expects you to want to do, but nothing like what I want to do. It points to a startup pack and some samples, but again these are very fully featured and not what I want to do, and trying to work backwards from them is proving intractible.

What's lacking is something that describes how to create a custom policy from scratch and take full control of the process of authenticating the user.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to go about this, or know of some good documentation about this kind of thing?

Comment: First read [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/readme.md), once you understand how that works, your solution is simple, pretty much remove all orchestration steps between the start and end of the user journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-different-identity-repository-for-authentication-using-azure-ad-b2c-e662bf17e072).

Basically, self-asserted screen to get credentials, verify against API, send JWT to application.

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: More here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/rest-api-idp

Comment: Worked perfectly. I dread to think how long it would have taken me to work that out. The MSDN documentation is Byzantine.